# PHP sendmail if elseif

Tags: php, email, input, sendmail

I'm trying all day and can't get this to work.

I have four `input type="radio" name="sector" value="value1"` but can't get this to work.

```
function emailtotest($to) {
    if (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value1') {
        $to .= 'email1@domain.com';
    } elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value2') {
        $to .= 'email2@domain.com';
    } elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value3') {
        $to .= 'email3@domain.com';
    } elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value4') {
        $to .= 'email4@domain.com';
    } else {
        $to .= 'email5@domain.com';
    }
    return $to;
}
```

I already test the sendmail.php and it's working perfectly if I declare `$to = email@dominio.com`, but with the radio inputs won't work.

Any help please?

The form code:

```
    <form id="contactForm" action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="nome">Nome</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required="required" class="input_full">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="tel">Telefone</label><br>
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" required="required" class="input_full">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">E-mail</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="nome@exemplo.com" required="required" class="input_full">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="radio_1">
            <input type="radio" id="radio_1" name="sector" value="value1">
            Comercial / Marketing
        </label>
        <label for="radio_2">
            <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="sector" value="value2">
            Produto / Manutenção
        </label>
        <label for="radio_3">
            <input type="radio" id="radio_3" name="sector" value="value3">
            Financeiro
        </label>
        <label for="radio_4">
            <input type="radio" id="radio_4" name="sector" value="value4">
            Administração
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label><br>
        <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" rows="5" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem." required="required" class="input_full"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar &rarr;">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: A little suggestion - you should keep the value of `strip_tags($_POST['sector'])` in a variable. It helps to not repeat yourself. As for the actual question... are you forgetting the `name` attribute of the radiobutton? You need to set them all to `sector`. Also, your form's `method` needs to be `POST`...

Comment: How are you calling this function? You're appending to `$to` but we can't see what `$to` begins as.

Comment: You specify in your question that you have tags reading `<input type="radio" value="value1">`, but did you remember to give those input buttons a name? So they should read `<input type="radio" name="sector" value="value1">`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `.=`?

Comment: @MattF The input has the name of "sector" already.

Comment: Guys, I don't know nothing about php, I'm blind here. The code abode is all the code for $to that I have… about using `.=` I don't know the alternatives :S

Comment: If you want to pass $to as reference, you should change the input argument to `&$to` and if you want to use the function to return one address, then the input argument ($to) and `.=` seems redundant.

Comment: @fardjad 1. Yes! 2. How can I do that?

Comment: You may need to post your entire HTML for us to get a handle on what's going on. Well, not the entire HTML - just everything from the opening form tag to the closing form tag.

Comment: it should be something like: 
function emailtotest() {
if (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value1') return 'email1@domain.com';
// ...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm HTML part looks ok but try to correct this:

```
function emailtotest($to) {
if (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value1') {
    $to = 'email1@domain.com';
} elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value2') {
    $to = 'email2@domain.com';
} elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value3') {
    $to = 'email3@domain.com';
} elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value4') {
    $to = 'email4@domain.com';
} else {
    $to = 'email5@domain.com';
}
return $to;
```

}

So instead of $to .= "email.."; use just $to = "email"; so without dot before =

Why?

Because if you use .= it means that you add a value to existing value. So example if $to already contains this value: email@email.com and then you use $to.= "email1@email.com"; then $to will contains BOTH values and will look like this: email@email.comemail1@email.com
Which is not really OK. The other (same) solution is also this:

```
function emailtotest($to) {
if (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value1') {
return 'email1@domain.com';
} elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value2') {
return 'email2@domain.com';
} elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value3') {
return 'email3@domain.com';
} elseif (strip_tags($_POST['sector']) == 'value4') {
return 'email4@domain.com';
} else {
return 'email5@domain.com';
}
}
```

That's one thing and another try NOT to using $_POST in functions even it's global. Get the value from $_POST example:

```
$which = trim(strip_tags($_POST['sector'])); //get your checkbox value
```

And then call a function and take $which into function like:

```
$to_email = emailtotest($which); //call a function and take $which - value1, value2...
mail($to_email, "subject", "email txt"); //then send a mail to $to_email

function emailtotest($value){
if($value=='value1'){
return 'email1@domain.com';
}
else if ($value=='value2'){
return 'email2@domain.com'
.....
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now it works and I begin to understand some PHP :D